# Не применяются медиа запрос

Tags: media-queries

Мне нужно чтобы на мониторах с большим разрешением свойства:

```
max-height: 350px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Не применялись когда ширина монитора начинается с 1000px, прописал следующее:

```
.main-section__sidebar__content {
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 350px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   color: #303133;
   font: 14px/17px 'latoregular', sans-serif;
}
@media (min-widh:1000px) and (max-width:3000px){

    .main-section__sidebar__content {
        max-height: none;
        overflow-y: visible;
    }
}
```

не понимаю в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `max-height/max-width` стоит использовать `inherit`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width:3000px) { ... max-height: inherit; ... }
```

```css
.main-section__sidebar__content { 
  width: 100%; 
  max-height: 350px; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  color: #303133; 
  font: 14px/17px 'latoregular', sans-serif;
} 

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width:3000px){

  .main-section__sidebar__content {
      max-height: inherit;
      overflow-y: visible;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section__sidebar__content">
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо Вам большое!!!